# How to load CSV file with header in the fifth row and with multiple line records in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 3.2.1

My goal is to read a CSV file that has the header on the 5th row and also has some records with multiple lines.

A solution to read multiple line records that works is this one:

```
sourcePath = "s3://mybucket/location/file.csv"
df = spark.read.csv(sourcePath, multiLine=True)
```

And a solution to read the header on the 5th row is this one:

```
sourcePath = "s3://mybucket/location/file.csv"
source_rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(sourcePath).zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: x[1] > int(4)).map(lambda x: x[0])
df = spark.read.csv(source_rdd, header=True)
```

The problem happens when I want to use both solutions:

```
skip_rows=4
sourcePath = "s3://mybucket/location/file.csv"
source_rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(sourcePath).zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: x[1] > int(skip_rows)).map(lambda x: x[0])
df = spark.read.csv(source_rdd, header=True, multiLine=True)
```

The multiLine option is ignored when I pass an RDD instead of the source path.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `skipRows` parameter to `load` function:

```
sourcePath = "s3://mybucket/location/file.csv"

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("multiLine", "true").load(sourcePath, skipRows=4)
```

Comment: Doesn't SkipRows only work on Pandas?

I think that functionality is not available on Spark yet: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26406

Comment: They must've added it after this ticket was solved anyway and didn't update that ticket, tested it myself - it works.